# Getting error Could not load file or assembly 'System.Drawing.Common, Version=6.0.0.0 while executing swagger api which is hosted on elastic beanstalk

Tags: .net-core, iis, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have hosted my .net core application on Elastic beanstalk to use API to sign the pdf.
The application is hosted successfully but getting 500 internal server error

 I logged into my server to get a brief idea of the error in the event viewer and got `System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Drawing.Common, Version=6.0.0.0,`  in the windows logs application section

Note: application is hosted with elastic beanstalk with IIS 10.0 running on 64bit Windows Server 2019/2.11.2 version

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the buildspec.sh file which is used while using codebuild 
In postBuild part where we have to zip our publish file, we should use the following command 
`zip ../{appname}.zip -r * .[^.]*`

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/applications-sourcebundle.html

Answer (score 0):

Usually, for this type of error, you first need to inspect your project and verify that the package.dll exists.

Check your application project’s dependencies list and make sure the dll file is referenced successfully. System.Drawing.Common 6.0.0 dependencies refer to: https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Drawing.Common/6.0.0#dependencies-body-tab.

Finally, you can try to uninstall and reinstall the System.Drawing.Commo package you need through NuGet Manager.

In order to further locate the exact cause of the 500 error. You could enable FRT: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshoot-with-failed-request-tracing

Comment: I have already checked all the dependencies for System.drawing.Common also tried uninstalling it but got same error

Comment: Have you deployed your .net core application on local IIS?Are you experiencing the same problem in local IIS? If it works fine locally, it may be caused by Elastic beanstalk configuration.